# Alternative to DTMF data transmission for Asterisk PBX connection

Tags: websocket, asterisk, sip, pbx, dtmf

We are working on a legacy project in which we are connecting to Asterisk PBX using data sent over DTMF. We are exploring using alternatives to DTMF and have zeroed in on SMS and web sockets. What will be the best approach to implement this?

Asterisk v11 is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you use analog, you can use tone-based modems like iaxmodem or alarm reciver in asterisk.

if you are using sip, most logical will be use of sip messages.